# Issue posting data to web server with NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, post, https, webserver

I'm using `NSMutableURLRequest` to post some data to a password protected web server. I've gotten connected and everything, and I can retrieve data fine, but for some reason I am not able to post any.

I'm using `NSURLCredentials` for the username and password, and connecting is no problem.

Starting URL request:

```
-(void)starting {
NSURL *url = [NSURL
URLWithString:@"http:myurl/myfile.txt"];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self]; //Calling NSURLConnection delegate methods
}
```

Converting `NSString` I want to post to `NSData`:

```
NSString *someString = @"Hello World";
NSData* theData=[someString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *someUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl/myfile.txt"];
```

Writing to web server:

```
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [theData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:someUrl];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];    
[request setHTTPBody:theData];
```

Allow any https certificates:

```
[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[someUrl host]];
```

Sending request for retrieval:

```
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Does length of retrieved data = 0..

```
if ([data length] == 0) {

    UIAlertView *dataLengthNoneAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No data" message:@"There is no data on the server" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [dataLengthNoneAlert show];

}
```

If not, tell me new data.. (Which should be "Hello World")

```
else {

    NSLog(data);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Retrieved data" message:data delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dimiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alert show];

}
```

So I 'attempt' to post the data to the web server, and then retrieve it right after. I find that the length of the data I just supposedly wrote is 0. I even check the server outside of the application, and nothing changes. The url is valid. This is my first time using NSMutableURLRequest, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete expert but a couple of things to try that have worked for me.

It might be better to store your response as type `NSMutableData` instead of `NSData` because this allows for a continous dynamic response

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Also apples documentation of `NSUrlconnection`^ suggests the use of 4 methods, `didRecieveResponse, didRecieveData, didFailwithError` and `didFinishLoading` which aid in appending and interpreting data.

hope this helps.

Comment: `NSURLConnection's` method of `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` is working fine in interpreting the server's data. The issue is posting to it.

Comment: Try 'NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [someString UTF8String] length:[someString length]];'    and 'NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:someURL];

Comment: That request was included in starting the authentication (which I didn't include in the question) and `NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [someString UTF8String] length:[someString length]];` didn't change anything. But maybe the encoding type has something to do with it...

Comment: Well now I know what I'm doing terribly wrong, I don't have a php script to process the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your your **url string** end with slash:

This work:

```
http://your.url/
```

This **doesn't** work:

```
http://your.url
```